# Woocommerce checkout AJAX PHP

Tags: php, ajax, woocommerce

When creating the PHP for an AJAX function in my woocommerce checkout page, I use a $.post.   What all needs to be in the PHP (via $.post)  in order to call $woocommerce->session->set

I tried the following in the php of the $.post

```
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->session->set('_delivery_loading', $temp);
```

However the PHP is reporting that it does not know what $woocommerce->session->set is.

How does the PHP that is the target of a $.post (from AJAX) know about woocommerce?

Here is my callback php (test.php):

```
<?php
global $woocommerce;
$temp = $_GET["pass_var"];
$woocommerce->session->set('_delivery_loading', $temp);
?>
```

And here is my jQuery in my checkout.php

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $("#myradiobutton").change(function(){            

         var padded_variable = "0";

        $.get('test.php',{pass_var:passed_variable}, function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });

     location.reload();                
     });

});
```

Comment: Please add more of your code, especially the javascript part. The question is too hard to understand without more code.

Comment: I have an AJAX function in my checkout page, that then calls mytest.php.  mytest.php needs to set a session variable that function.php can retrieve.  What is needed in mytest.php in order to call the $woocommerce->session->set method

Comment: Don't know if this is the cause or not, but `$woocommerce` has been deprecated in favor of `WC()`.

Comment: And do post your whole PHP callback function.

Comment: PHP callback function posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I discovered the answer.

Turns out that your PHP callback has to include

```
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/wp-blog-header.php");
```

at the top in order to call WC functions.